# Are lower and uppercase valid for boolean literals in apache age?

Tags: apache-age

While reading through the age documentation on valid data types [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html). There are valid boolean types with keywords `TRUE` `FALSE` `NULL` all uppercased
for example as shown in the documentation

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    RETURN TRUE
$$) AS (boolean_result agtype);
```

But when using the boolean types in data types like maps or list it's in lowercase as used in the documentation

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    WITH {int_key: 1, float_key: 1.0, numeric_key: 1::numeric, bool_key: true, string_key: 'Value'} as m
    RETURN m
$$) AS (m agtype);
```

So does that the mean they can be interchanged (uppercase<=>lowercase) or only use lowercased boolean when using data types like map, list.

It was explicitly stated in the documentation that

**Boolean constants can be represented in Cypher queries by the keywords TRUE, FALSE, and NULL.**

Answer (score 1):

As these are case insensitive so you can use both TRUE and true. It will serve the same purpose.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    RETURN **TRUE**
$$) AS (boolean_result agtype);

or 

SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    RETURN true
$$) AS (boolean_result agtype);
```

both will return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The data type names (numeric, bool, int) and their values (for example true, null etc) are case insensitive which means that

> So does that the mean they can be interchanged (uppercase<=>lowercase)

is correct

Answer (score 0):

The keywords TRUE, FALSE, and NULL are case-insensitive, which means that they can be written in either uppercase or lowercase without affecting their recognition by the parser.

For example, in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
  ReTuRn TrUe
$$) AS (res agtype);

 res  
------
 true
(1 row)
```

The keyword "TRUE" is written in mixed-case letters, but it is still returns "true".

Answer (score 0):

According to the the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html#bool), it wasn't stated if the Bool values are case sensitive. Hence, you are very correct with the statement "So does that the mean they can be interchanged (uppercase<=>lowercase)....".

Answer (score 0):

This is an ambiguity in the documentation, but yes in general the keywords are case-insensitive (like in SQL) and you can use both interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can be used interchangeably in either uppercase or lowercase and it won't affect their recognition by the parser.
Although the documentation only mentions **TRUE**, **true** will also be understood as boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html#bool) AGE provides the standard Cypher type boolean which is **case-insensitive** and can have several states i.e **true**, **false** and also a third state **unknown**, which is represented by the Agtype null value.

Be careful with null though since the parser understand that true and false are of type boolean but **null** can have any type therefore in some contexts you might have to cast null to boolean explicitly, for example `NULL::boolean`. Conversely, the cast can be omitted from a string-literal Boolean value in contexts where the parser can deduce that the literal must be of type boolean

Answer (score -1):

All keywords in AGE are case insensitive, just like with standard PostgreSQL syntax. The following query is valid:

```
SEleCT * 
FROM cYpher('customers',
$$
    MaTcH (p)
    ReTURN p
$$
) as (p aGtype);
                                                       p                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "person", "properties": {"last_name": "Smith", "first_name": "Adam"}}::vertex
(1 row)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you got it right. Whether you write it True or TRUE or true, it will all return true. As these are case insensitive.